# Installing ia32-libs in ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ubuntu, x86

I am trying to install the 32 bit libarries for ubuntu on my ubuntu 64bit version 12.04 because i cannot setup the android SDK and AVD as it is. Each time i run the command

```
  sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
```

I get this error

```
  Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
ia32-libs is already the newest version.
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ia32-libs-multiarch:i386 : Depends: gtk2-engines:i386 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Running sudo at-get -f doesnt help either.What could be the issue?

Answer (score -1):

1st install Synaptic from terminal window

```
sudo apt-get install synaptic
```

2nd insert line in code

```
 deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring main restricted universe multiverse
```

3rd update the your system

```
 sudo apt-get update
```

and then

```
  sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
```